# How do i stop execution of my code

Tags: vba, excel

```
For i=0 to 100000

 MsgBox("Whats up")


 Next i
```

I was trying to test if my FOR loop works and now i cant stop the execution of the programme. The break button doesnt work , i can only press OK . I need help

Thanks

Comment: If you're using an IDE, set a breakpoint and use the debugger.

Comment: What do you mean "cant"? What have you tried? And what are you really trying to do. Edit: Wait is this a programming question (eg trying to inspect program data during execution) or a general computer issue (frozen)?

Comment: i read online about ctrl-break but i cant find the break button on my keyboard so i though it did not exist

Comment: If you are using a HP computer, this is a problem, because it is missing a Break key. I had to reassign a key for break on this machine. Sometimes you will find you have an on-screen keyboard that will work. You can also try various combinations of alt,fn,ctrl,esc,pause but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl+Break usually works. Not just Break by itself.

Comment: is break a button on the keyboard??

Comment: Sometimes... often attached to the 'Pause' button.

Answer (score 4):

in address to "Your code"
As [RJ Lohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897994/rj-lohan) has mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> also works

And in other case, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> is handled by that procedure/window. You can try <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

And make sure  in VBA the application setting is :
   `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt`

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager, find the process for your program under the Processes tab, End Process.

Comment: Save Early, Save Often. Save Early, Save Often. Save Early, Save Often.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should shut down your machine.

Comment: I'm not sure what to think of this